# Google autocomplete places, venue name to lat/lng

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using the autocompleteplaces from google on my android app, sometimes you can fill in a venue name and it autocompletes it for you like here:

[image]

I want to get the lat/lng from it so I use geocoder:

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(autoCompView.getText().toString(), 1);

                    if (addresses.size() >  0) {
                        latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
                        longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
```

Now it doesn't give me any adress because the name of the venue is in it.
How can I get the lat/lng from it?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Autocomplete Place API returns an `id` and a `reference`.
You can use this returned `id` to query the Places API and get latitude/longitude information from it.

For more details see:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_results

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests

Answer (score 0):

This was my code that I've implemented.

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
        getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setCountry("KE")
            .build();

    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i("Place: " , String.valueOf(place.getName()));
            mMap.clear();
            displayMarkersOnMap();
            LatLng selectedPlace = place.getLatLng();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(selectedPlace));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
            MarkerOptions selectedPlaceMarker = new MarkerOptions();
            selectedPlaceMarker.position(selectedPlace);
            selectedPlaceMarker.title(String.valueOf(place.getName()));
            mMap.addMarker(selectedPlaceMarker);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("An error occurred: " , String.valueOf(status));
        }
    });
```

Basically, I've added the filter to filter the results to my country Kenya at the top. I then create a placeSelectedListener that will be called when the user clicks a location. from it, I assign the LatLng received from the place and move my map to it.